# Regex matching only words inside custom tag

Tags: regex

I'm fairly new to regex and trying to figure out a pattern that will only match the instance of the word inside my custom tag.

In the example below both words match the condition of being after a | and before a ]

```
Pattern: (?=|)singleline(?=.*])

Sample: [if @sample|singleline second] <p>Another statement singleline goes here</p> [/if]
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and expected output you're looking to produce?

Comment: Just looking to match the condition as true. May want to remove the word:  `$pattern = '%(?=\|)singleline(?=.*])%';  
    $output  = preg_replace($pattern, "", $output);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> words that match the condition of being after a | and before a ]

the `.*`, which means *"anything, zero or more times, and be greedy about it"*, will race to the end of the string and back up only enough to get to a `]`  (the *last* one). (and your lookbehind is a lookahead):

if you really want to match what you say you want to match (see quote), then this is it:

```
Pattern: (?<=|)(\w+)(?=])
```

Edit: or this one if you want to "*match alphanumerics and spaces inside | and ]*":

```
Pattern: (?<=|)([\w\s]+?)(?=])
```

Answer (score 1):

`(?=|)` asserts that the next thing in the string either nothing or nothing.  That will always evaluate to `true`; it's always possible to match nothing.  I think sweaver2112 is correct that you meant to use a lookbehind there, but you also need to escape the pipe: `(?<=\|)`.  Or just match a pipe in the normal way; I don't see any need to use lookarounds for that part.

The other part probably does need to be a lookahead, but you need to expand it a bit.  You want to assert that the word is followed by a closing bracket, but not if there's an opening bracket first.  Assuming the brackets are always correctly paired, that should mean the word is between a pair of them.  Like this:

```
Pattern: \|singleline(?=[^\]\[]*\])
```

`[^\]\[]*\]` matches zero or more of any characters except `]` or `[`, followed by a `]`.  The backslashes escaping the "real" brackets may or may not be necessary depending on the regex flavor, but escaping them is always safe.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, the lookahead is a big help. I've got this: `(?<=@sample|.)singleline(?=[^\]\[]*\])` It's working so far except it matches any @word not just the specified

Comment: Does `(?<=@sample\|)singleline(?=[^\]\[]*\])` do what you want?  I'm still not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish; maybe `(?:@sample\|)?singleline(?=[^\]\[]*\])` will serve.